# Remove Objects from Legend When You Have Also Used Fit, Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I've plotted data points and fitted an exponential curve between them using 'fit' in Matlab. The problem is that with the fit-function I got the fitted line I wanted to plot, but also extra markers on top of my regular markers. I solved this problem by plotting the wanted markers on top of the unwanted so that they couldn't be seen. Now to the problem. When I want to show the legends those dots are also in there. How can I remove the markers from the legend without removing the fitted line since both of them are hidden inside the fit-function? Can I stop 'fit' from plotting the unwanted markers? So, I want to remove the blue dot called 'hoff' in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leave out legend-entries by manually leaving out the handles of the lines, that you dont want to be in the legend. Try this:

```
%if you plot something, that you want showing up in the legend, save its handle:
h_line = plot(x,y)
%you dont want to show up this line? dont do anything, just plot it:
plot(myMarker)
%then set the legend-> you can add the text for your legend-entries with 
%a cell-array   containing the strings you want to show up:
legend([h_line another_line],{'Text1' 'Text2'})
```

with the example (see comments) I came to this solution:

```
close all
X=[1:10];
Y=X*0.5+0.1;
ft = fittype('poly2'); 
f = fit(X', Y',ft); 
ha=plot(f)
hold on
hc=plot(X,Y)
hb=errorbar(X, Y, X*0.1, 'squarek','MarkerFaceColor','k','markersize',5)
hleg1 = legend([ha hc],{'hnh','ghg'});
```

-> this is just about splitting the plot-command. Hope that helps...

the result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I've tried that. The problem is that when I plot the fitted line I get both the red line and the blue dots. I want to have the black markers and the red line in my plot. If I want to name the plot which gives me the fitted line the blue dots will be in there as well.

Comment: %Generate fitted line:
ft = fittype('exp1');
f = fit(X', Y',ft);

plot(f,X ,Y)
errorbar(X, Y, Error, 'squarek','MarkerFaceColor','k','markersize',5)

hleg1 = legend('hoff','hnh','ghg');