# Write Equation from Fit in Legend, Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

So, I've fitted an exponential curve to some data points using 'fit' and now I want to get the equation of the fitted curve in the Legend in the graph. How can I do that? I want to have an equation on the form y=Ce^-xt in the legend. Can I get the coefficients, C and x from the fitted curve and then put the equation inside the legend? Or can I get the whole equation written out in some way? I have many plotted graphs so I would be grateful if the method is not so much time consuming.

Edit: Perhaps I was unclear. The main problem is how I should get out the coefficients from the fitted line I've plotted. Then I want to have the equation inside the legend in my graph. Do I have to take out the coefficients by hand (and how can it be done?) or can Matlab write it straight out like in, for example, excel?

Comment: you can take a look to my answer here: [legend with fit-fcn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104987/remove-objects-from-legend-when-you-have-also-used-fit-matlab/18105284#18105284)

Comment: That's the question I posted yesterday and I have done all that :P. Take a look at my edit and perhaps you'll understand my question.

Comment: I see :) and there are two good answers already :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/curvefit/coeffvalues.html) explains that you can obtain the coefficients derived from a fit executed as `c = fit(...)`, as

```
coef=coeffvalues(c) 
C=coef(1)
x=coef(2)
```

You can create your own legend as illustrated by the following example.

Defining `C` and `x` as the parameters from your fits,

```
% simulate and plot some data
t= [0:0.1:1];
C = 0.9;
x = 1;
figure, hold on
plot(t,C*exp(-x*t)+ 0.1*randn(1,length(t)),'ok', 'MarkerFaceColor','k')
plot(t,C*exp(-x*t),':k')
axis([-.1 1.2 0 1.2])

% here we add the "legend"
line([0.62 0.7],[1 1],'Linestyle',':','color','k')
text(0.6,1,[ '               ' num2str(C,'%.2f'),' exp(-' num2str(x,'%.2f') ' t)   ' ],'EdgeColor','k')
set(gca,'box','on')
```

Example output:

[image]

You may have to adjust number formatting and the size of the text box to suit your needs.

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, but how do I get the coefficients C and x? I only have a fitted line (from the 'fit'-function) but no values for the coefficients. Is there not a way for Matlab to write out the formula of the fitted line like in for example Excel?

Comment: @Djamillah I added an explanation on how to get the parameters, let me know if it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a piece of code that will display the fitted equation in the legend box. You can reduce the amount of digits in the legend by manipulating the `sprintf` option: `%f` to `%3.2f` for example.

```
%some data
load census
s = fitoptions('Method','NonlinearLeastSquares','Lower',[0,0],'Upper',[Inf,max(cdate)],'Startpoint',[1 1]);
f = fittype('a*(x-b)^n','problem','n','options',s);

%fit, plot and legend
[c2,gof2] = fit(cdate,pop,f,'problem',2)
plot(c2,'m');
legend(sprintf('%f * (x - %f)^%d',c2.a,c2.b,c2.n));
```

The command `disp(c2)` will display in the command window what is stored in the `fit` object. Also, by enabling the "datatip in edit mode" option (Matlab preferences, then Editor, then Display), you will have an instant view on the data stored by putting your mouse cursor over an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
function [S]=evaFit(ffit)
  S=sprintf('y=%s',formula(ffit));
  S2='';
  N=coeffnames(ffit);
  V=coeffvalues(ffit);
  for i= 1:numcoeffs(ffit)
      S2=sprintf('%s %c=%f',S2, string(N(i)), V(i));
  end
  S=sprintf('%s%s',S, S2);
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.