# Matlab fitlm plot - get the fit equation on the graph automatically

Tags: matlab, plot, legend, model-fitting

I have a table of data:

```
Var1                Var2
5.18030000000000    4.29744584300000
5.15310000000000    3.85636524000000
5.26250000000000    4.12758213600000
5.22220000000000    4.40338994300000
5.00530000000000    3.92876037500000
4.88410000000000    3.70133370700000
4.78160000000000    3.63423577700000
4.97240000000000    3.84435824200000
5.22330000000000    3.96584081000000
5.29300000000000    3.94783031300000
5.79150000000000    4.45106478800000
5.69850000000000    4.31898781000000
5.81800000000000    4.41928155800000
5.72890000000000    4.43729205500000
```

following the mathworks help for fitlm, i made a table.
next, used fitlm:

```
 a=fitlm(table1,'Var1 ~ Var2')
```

followed by plotting:

```
h=plot(fitlm)
```

based on the help file, i should get the legend to include the fit equation
however, in my plot i only get the name fit. 
attached is the image 
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z7YQ.jpg)

i know i can, in theory, get the co-ordinates and strings of the legend, and apply the equation using text and legend again. like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122848/write-equation-from-fit-in-legend-matlab), however, i want to understand what went wrong, and where... 
any help would be appreciated.

this is the help code, in case you can't find it. just run it and see the results:

```
load carsmall
tbl = table(MPG,Weight);
tbl.Year = ordinal(Model_Year);
mdl = fitlm(tbl,'MPG ~ Year + Weight^2');
h1=plot(mdl)
```

their [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFGRC.png)

Comment: I noticed from the carsmall example that if you leave out the tbl.Year line, so not adding anything extra to the tbl after creating it, the equation is also left out. So I added an extra column to your table  `table1.test = ones(14,1); a=fitlm(table1,'Var1 ~ Var2 + test');` and now it gives the equation. I don't know why yet.

Comment: hmm, that is awesome! thank you. i did a similar trick. from the carsmall model. mdl = fitlm(tbl,'MPG ~ Weight + Weight^2'); and you don't get a fit equation as well. i think it only displays the equation when there is more then one parameter because the model is LINEAR and not two variable model. it makes a fit, and you need to know the fit. i couldn't find it in the documentation yet.so it's just an assumption

Comment: @m7913d: we are not sure yet why the equation for one variable is not shown. In the end, even if there is only one variable, a linear fit can be made so the equation should be known.